# How to show full network path of a file on a mounted share in OS X

Tags: macos, bash

Given I have a mounted share, in say:

```
/Volumes/temp
```

This might map to

```
cifs://servername/temp
```

Using bash, how do I get the network path to a file on the share, such as

```
/Volumes/temp/folder/file.txt
```

Comment: What is the problem with the obious `cifs://servername/temp/folder/file.txt`?

Comment: I want a script to deduce cifs://servername/temp/folder/file.txt from the mounted path /Volumes/temp/folder/file.txt

Comment: This is a good question.  It's easy to get the "UNC" path to a file or mounted drive in Windows, but I haven't seen it for the Mac yet.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to replace the beginning of the path. You can do it this way:

```
file='/Volumes/temp/folder/file.txt'
echo ${file/#\/Volumes/cifs://servername}
```

This is described in `man bash`:

```
   ${parameter/pattern/string}
          Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pat‐
          tern just as in pathname expansion.  Parameter is  expanded  and
          the  longest match of pattern against its value is replaced with
          string.  If pattern begins with /, all matches  of  pattern  are
          replaced   with  string.   Normally  only  the  first  match  is
          replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at the begin‐
          ning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern begins with
          %, it must match at the end of the expanded value of  parameter.
          [...]
```

Comment: I can do a replace, my question is how to resolve that /Volumes/temp actually points to cifs://servername.

Comment: I would expect `mount` to tell you this kind of information.